# Unique values in synchronized array

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I store a synchronized array of some kind of ids per user.
In a web app I have two function: `addId(id)` and `removeId(id)` and I translate them into proper `synchronizedArray.$add(id)` and `synchronizedArray.$remove(getRefForId(id))`.

In the storage I have:
root > users > $uid > data > ids: `synchronizedArray` is defined as:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp/firebaseio.com/users/' + userUid + '/data/ids');
var synchronizedArray = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Is there any way to validate this synchronized array in a way that user cannot add the same id multiple times (in other words: in a way that values in users's data/ids are unique)?

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the data doesn't get overwritten is easy with [Firebase's Security Rules language](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/). From that guide:

> To illustrate, consider a rule that would allow us to create new records or delete existing ones, as long as data does not already exist at a given path, but not to make changes to the data:

```
// we can write as long as old data or new data does not exist
// in other words, if this is a delete or a create, but not an update
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```

But if you're using `$add()` your ids are statistically guaranteed to be unique already. See [this article about Firebase's so-called push ids](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html).

Comment: I don't want the keys to be unique. I need values to be unique.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to ensure unique values, so you'll have to change/augment your data structure to turn those values into keys. Probably something similar to the [indexes documented here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices).